# ¿Cómo hacer que no se escoja la misma carta 2 veces?

Tags: javascript

Cómo se le puede hacer para que no salgan cartas repetidas? Utilizo un numero aleatorio para seleccionar una posición dentro del arreglo cartas, pero este numero puede repetirse ocasionando que salga una carta repetida. Como puede hacerse para simular que el mazo va a perdiendo cartas cada vez que el usuario toma una ya que de la manera que el programa esta siendo ejecutado puede ocasionar que por ejemplo la carta as de diamantes salga dos veces, lo cual en un maso normal de cartas es imposible.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .maso{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            .tablero{
                display: flex;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }
            .carta{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            var cartas = [
                //Treboles
                "A♣",
                "2♣",
                "3♣",
                "4♣",
                "5♣",
                "6♣",
                "7♣",
                "8♣",
                "9♣",
                "10♣",
                "J♣",
                "Q♣",
                "R♣",
                //Corazones
                "A♥",
                "2♥",
                "3♥",
                "4♥",
                "5♥",
                "6♥",
                "7♥",
                "8♥",
                "9♥",
                "10♥",
                "J♥",
                "Q♥",
                "R♥",
                //Espadas
                "A♠",
                "2♠",
                "3♠",
                "4♠",
                "5♠",
                "6♠",
                "7♠",
                "8♠",
                "9♠",
                "10♠",
                "J♠",
                "Q♠",
                "R♠",
                //Diamantes
                "A♦",
                "2♦",
                "3♦",
                "4♦",
                "5♦",
                "6♦",
                "7♦",
                "8♦",
                "9♦",
                "10♦",
                "J♦",
                "Q♦",
                "R♦"
            ];

            function tomarCarta(){
                var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);
                var b = cartas[a];
                var x = document.createElement("DIV");
                x.classList.add("carta");
                var y = document.createTextNode(b);
                x.appendChild(y);
                document.getElementById("tablero").appendChild(x);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maso" onclick="tomarCarta()">
        </div>
        <div id="tablero" class="tablero">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas guardar las selecciones en otro array y chequear si cada carta ya ha sido seleccionada.  Algo asi:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .maso{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            .tablero{
                display: flex;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }
            .carta{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            var cartas = [
                //Treboles
                "A♣",
                "2♣",
                "3♣",
                "4♣",
                "5♣",
                "6♣",
                "7♣",
                "8♣",
                "9♣",
                "10♣",
                "J♣",
                "Q♣",
                "R♣",
                //Corazones
                "A♥",
                "2♥",
                "3♥",
                "4♥",
                "5♥",
                "6♥",
                "7♥",
                "8♥",
                "9♥",
                "10♥",
                "J♥",
                "Q♥",
                "R♥",
                //Espadas
                "A♠",
                "2♠",
                "3♠",
                "4♠",
                "5♠",
                "6♠",
                "7♠",
                "8♠",
                "9♠",
                "10♠",
                "J♠",
                "Q♠",
                "R♠",
                //Diamantes
                "A♦",
                "2♦",
                "3♦",
                "4♦",
                "5♦",
                "6♦",
                "7♦",
                "8♦",
                "9♦",
                "10♦",
                "J♦",
                "Q♦",
                "R♦"
            ];
            var usadas = [];

            function tomarCarta(){
                var cartaValida = false;
                while (!cartaValida) {
                  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);              
                  var b = cartas[a];
                  if (usadas.indexOf(b) == -1) {
                    usadas.push(b);
                    var x = document.createElement("DIV");
                    x.classList.add("carta");
                    var y = document.createTextNode(b);
                    x.appendChild(y);
                    document.getElementById("tablero").appendChild(x);
                    cartaValida = true;
                  }
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maso" onclick="tomarCarta()">
        </div>
        <div id="tablero" class="tablero">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo porque es que funciona.  En que parte checa si la carta ya fue seleccionada?

Comment: En esta linea `if (usadas.indexOf(b) == -1) {`

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con el metodo [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)

ejemplo:

```js
       var cartas = [
                //Treboles
                "A♣",
                "2♣",
                "3♣",
                "4♣",
                "5♣",
                "6♣",
                "7♣",
                "8♣",
                "9♣",
                "10♣",
                "J♣",
                "Q♣",
                "R♣",
                //Corazones
                "A♥",
                "2♥",
                "3♥",
                "4♥",
                "5♥",
                "6♥",
                "7♥",
                "8♥",
                "9♥",
                "10♥",
                "J♥",
                "Q♥",
                "R♥",
                //Espadas
                "A♠",
                "2♠",
                "3♠",
                "4♠",
                "5♠",
                "6♠",
                "7♠",
                "8♠",
                "9♠",
                "10♠",
                "J♠",
                "Q♠",
                "R♠",
                //Diamantes
                "A♦",
                "2♦",
                "3♦",
                "4♦",
                "5♦",
                "6♦",
                "7♦",
                "8♦",
                "9♦",
                "10♦",
                "J♦",
                "Q♦",
                "R♦"
            ];  
        function tomarCarta(){
                 // obtenemos la longitud del arreglo cartas con cartas.length 
                var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * cartas.length);
                var b = cartas[a];
                // removemos la posicion del arreglo
                // para evitar que se repita 
                cartas.splice(a, 1);
                var x = document.createElement("DIV");
                x.classList.add("carta");
                var y = document.createTextNode(b);
                x.appendChild(y);
                document.getElementById("tablero").appendChild(x);
            }
```

```css
.maso{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            .tablero{
                display: flex;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }
            .carta{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: CornSilk;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: CornflowerBlue;
                border-width: 4px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 5px;
            }
```

```html
<div class="maso" onclick="tomarCarta()">
        </div>
        <div id="tablero" class="tablero">
        </div>
```